# Whats mean of "http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/, does not properly navigate to the intended destination."?

Tags: american-english, do-support

My application is rejected with the follow information:

> Sender Apple

1. 5 SAFETY: DEVELOPER INFORMATION
2. 1 PERFORMANCE: APP COMPLETENESS
   Safety - 1.5

> The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/, does not properly navigate to the intended destination.

> Specifically, your support URL displayed “This site can’t be reached” error message.

> Next Steps

> Please revise your app’s support URL to ensure it directs users to a webpage with support information.

> Performance - 2.1

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone and iPad running iOS 10.2.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.

> Specifically, your app displayed a connection error when logging in with the provided demo accounts.

> Please see attached screenshots for details.

> Next Steps

> Please run your app on a device while connected to an IPv6 network (all apps must support IPv6) to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.

> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.

> Resources

> For information about supporting IPv6 Networks, please refer to Supporting IPv6 DNS64/NAT64 Networks and About Networking.

With the two follow images:

http://a1198.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple122/v4/60/8b/eb/608bebae-1c3b-cc93-2a01-9f512965f622/attachment-3951093649653869315Screenshot-0217-073348.png?downloadKey3=1487836993_30f3e33d7be2d3ba3c3e89d7e3393952

http://a1225.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple111/v4/58/78/7a/58787a76-b8a2-8016-e5fe-412c7fcaf8dc/attachment-8366771332257964417Screenshot-0217-073415.png?downloadKey3=1487836993_592f44ae84cf1f391301263be58175b6

And now I don't understand this information:

1)
"The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/, does not properly navigate to the intended destination"

and :

2)
"Specifically, your support URL displayed “This site can’t be reached” error message."

Can some friends explain the 1) and 2) detail to me ?

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem or are you just curious about the words in the message?  Given the detail here, I suspect that you're posting on the wrong site.  http://superuser.com/ would probably be the site for a technical problem like what you describe.

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks, I am curious abount the words in the message, where I have point out in my post. look at my last several lines.

Comment: Just so you realize that error messages aren't intended to be good English sentences.  The words have generic definitions, but what the messages actually mean requires understanding the technical details they relate to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain English translation:

> "The support URL specified in your app’s metadata, http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/, does not properly navigate to the intended destination"

- **App** is short for application.  That is the software.
- The **URL** is the human-readable web address.  It is what you type into the address window of your browser.  Programs besides your browser can also try to access a web address (for example, that's how software performs updates).
- **Metadata** is supplementary information about the software (as opposed to the actual program or data).  In this case, the software's metadata includes the web address for obtaining product support.
- http://hxsq.luminginfo.cn/ is apparently the URL specified in the software's metadata as the web location to get product support.  (It's a bad link, by the way.)
- Because it is not a working web address, it can't be used to navigate to the intended destination (the support site).

> "Specifically, your support URL displayed “This site can’t be reached” error message."

- Attempting to go to the support site using the non-working web address produced an error message stating that the site couldn't be reached.

Comment: BTW, just notice buried in the technical details that your problem relates to an iPhone.  If you plan to pursue help solving the problem, this would be off-topic on Super User, so ignore my previous suggestion.  The appropriate site would be http://apple.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: thanks your detail answer. I reached my site, I don't know if is American can not reach, you know Chinese has a greate firewall.